# firefox addon for post comment？

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

Is there a firefox addon for quick comment, because I don't want to input name ,email.. etc for every page Which I want post a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You need a form filler addon like [Sxipper](http://www.sxipper.com/) / [AutoFill Forms](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4775/) / [FormFiller](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1882/)

Answer (score 1):

[LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) is a program you can use across Chrome/FF/IE and while it's mainly for Passwords, it also gives you the ability to create profiles to fast fill forms automatically.

I've been using it for a couple of years now and I've found it to be one of the best extensions out there.